# How to select a specific attribute from Postgres JSONB column

Tags: postgresql

I have JSON stored in a jsonb column:

```
[
  {
    "ORDER_TYPE": "foo",
    "PAYMENT_TYPE": "VISA",
  }
]
```

I can query fine but is it possible to select specific parts (PAYMENT_TYPE) of the json from the resultset?

```
SELECT PAYMENT_TYPE 
FROM tools.orders 
WHERE responsejsonb::jsonb @> '[{"ORDER_TYPE":"foo"}]';
```

Desired output "PAYMENT_TYPE": "VISA" or "VISA"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flatten the JSONB array first.

```sql
select j ->> 'PAYMENT_TYPE' as payment_type -- and other expressions?
from tools.orders
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(responsejsonb::jsonb) as l(j)
where j ->> 'ORDER_TYPE' = 'foo';
```

**Edit**
If however the `responsejsonb` array has only one element (or only the first one matters) then it's simpler, the expression that you need is `responsejsonb::jsonb->0->>'PAYMENT_TYPE'`.

```sql
SELECT responsejsonb::jsonb->0->>'PAYMENT_TYPE'
FROM tools.orders 
WHERE responsejsonb::jsonb @> '[{"ORDER_TYPE":"foo"}]';
```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Is its implementation faster or is it a matter of taste? `j @> '{"ORDER_TYPE": "foo"}'`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a JSON path expression:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query_first(responsejsonb, '$[*] ? (@.ORDER_TYPE == "foo").PAYMENT_TYPE')
FROM tools.orders 
WHERE responsejsonb @> '[{"ORDER_TYPE":"foo"}]';
```

If you want all payment types, use `jsonb_path_query_array()` instead.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/kUvjjOc4)

---

If `responsejsonb` is really defined with the `jsonb` type, the cast to jsonb is useless.

Comment: I get this error when trying this: function jsonb_path_query_first(jsonb, unknown) does not exist

Comment: @IlyasPatel: [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/kUvjjOc4) maybe you are using an  older Postgres version

Comment: PostgreSQL 11.13 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit

Comment: this is the version I am using.

Comment: Amazon RDS - in AWS